# Div no se muestra al cambiarle display none;

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una caja que al cargar la página están con el estilo display: none; y no se muestran. Luego tengo un enlace que ejecuta una función js que hace que el display: none; cambie a display: block; y se muestren, pero dicha función parece que no funcione.

```
var visto = false;

function mostrar(id) {

    if(visto == false) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(id).style.display = "block";
        visto = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName(id).style.display = "none";
        visto = false;
    }
}
```

¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que el id que le estás pasando es correcto? Estás buscando por className, igual es que deberías buscar por id?

Comment: el id es correcto porque inspecciono el html y veo que se llama a la funcion onclick="mostrar('idcorrecta')"

Comment: Puede que llame a la id correcta pero a lo que se refiere es que para seleccionar el elemento no lo haces por su id si no por className, por lo que si el/los elementos no tienen una clase llamada igual que ese id no encontrará ningun elemento

Comment: Le llamé id solamente a la variable, pero, lo busco por className y tiene esa clase.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) para ocultar y [show](https://api.jquery.com/show/) para mostrar.

Comment: Esto sólo sería válido si tiene la libreria de jquery importada, no es una solución válida con javascript puro.

Comment: Y como lo haría con el ejemplo que tengo puesto ? @SebastianPaduano

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que show y hide son funciones de JQuery, una librería de selectores de JS. En tu caso, lo estás haciendo bien (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp).

Comment: @SebastianPaduano creo que mi problema es que al darle al enlace aunque pongo el display a block, la página vuelve a cargarse por lo que al cargarse el css de nuevo vuelve a estar el display en none. ¿ Cómo soluciono eso ?